# Trying to format a partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, windows

I am trying to change one of my partitions in order to install windows 10 on my Ubuntu new DELL laptop but I am having some problems.
I entered "Disks" option and when trying to format on of my partitions to NTFS I got a message says :

```
"error unmounting /dev/sda3:Command-Line 'unmount " /dev/sda3"" exited with non-zero exit status 32: unmount: /:target is busy (in some cases useful info about processes that use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1)).
(udisks-error-quark, 14)"
```

What is it?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this error before. If you have a duel boot Ubuntu and Windows 8+, you need to hold down the SHIFT key while powering down windows. Windows will still keep files open as if in a sleep mode and you will not be able to do a full mount or unmount from the computer while these files are in this state. Holding down SHIFT forces windows to do a complete shut down and you should then be able to boot into Ubuntu and change the partitions.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer.
I solved it by deleting all of the partitions via boot and then created new partition for windows.

Thanks!